# How to calculate work efficiency in terms of time

Tags: statistics

I need to calculate work efficiency of time spent on a task. Usually it is done by dividing planned time to elapsed time, but is there a way to add quotient that effects how much elapsed time exceeds estimate, or is less than estimate?

For example, given t<sub>p</sub> - planned time, t<sub>e</sub> - elapsed time:

t<sub>p</sub> = 10 min, t<sub>e</sub> = 15, efficiency is 66%

t<sub>p</sub> = 600 min, t<sub>e</sub> = 900, efficiency is still 66%

But time spent on first task exceeds estimate just by 5 minutes, whereas on second task it is 5 hours. I don't want to drag total statistics down because I don't care about small deviations from planned time, because well, 5 minutes is not 5 hours. As i understand, there should be basis by which to multiply or divide, let it be 60 minutes -- so, the more or less the difference in hours, the more/less effective work is.

I tried this to calculate standard efficiency E = t<sub>p</sub> / t<sub>e</sub> × 100, also time delta as t<sub>d</sub> = t<sub>e</sub> - t<sub>p</sub>, but that delta is not so big to affect anything (with 600/900 example if I substract delta from `E` I just got 61% instead of 66%). Maybe I need some exponential function?

The result I want to get is something like this (not actual result values):

t<sub>p</sub> = 10, t<sub>e</sub> = 10, efficiency is 1

t<sub>p</sub> = 10, t<sub>e</sub> = 5, efficiency is 1.12

t<sub>p</sub> = 600, t<sub>e</sub> = 320, efficiency is 1.8

t<sub>p</sub> = 600, t<sub>e</sub> = 900, efficiency is 0.33

t<sub>p</sub> = 10, t<sub>e</sub> = 15, efficiency is 0.87